# Eclipse Indigo no levanta , caso extraño y aislado

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee

resulta que trabajo con java , y usamos indigo...

Solo a mi me pasa el siguiente problema :

Estando el servidor levantado correctamente (con demora de 1.35 minutos) , lo bajo y creo un metodo o funcion , pero el problema es que al deployearlo no me levanta , me tarda demasiado .... 7 minutos o a veces me dice started failed.

Solucion mala : me pasan carpeta de ws entera y ahi me lavanta perfectamente . Ya no se que puede ser ,

Quiaza se la configuracion del eclipse , he borrado caches y eso y aun no se en donde me falla ... ..

El log del servidor no muestra la causa.

Alguno tuvo este inconveniente?

Comment: Bienvenido! Deberías ser algo más explícito. Te pasa con cualquier método o función? Es al crear un método o función nuevos? o también al modificarlos?

Comment: Has revisado el log o la consola que muestra? , saludos.

Comment: A Nivel de log no muestra nada .... como demora tanto en hacer los deploy , mas de 7 minutos , se hace automaticamente los undeploy....

Comment: Lo que tengo que hacer para que me funcione es volver a un workspace de respaldo , borrar todos los temporales y caches , y sincronizar con el repositorio , ahi me levanta normal demorando 1 minuto con 26 segundos